# translate a HTML select element in Grails

Tags: grails, internationalization

thought this would be easier.... imagine a `<g:select />` like this:

```
<g:select name="type.id" from="${Type.list()}"   
          value="${domainInstance?.type?.id}"  />
```

with two domain classes like this (please forgive me if these artificial classes are not error free)

```
class Domain {
  Type type
}

class Type {
  String name
}
```

I would now like to translate the entries of the select element. The following code first looked good:

```
<g:select name="type.id" from="${Type.list()}" 
            valueMessagePrefix="type.name"  
                value="${domainInstance?.type?.id}"  />
```

with entries in the messagebundle like this:

```
type.name.type1 = red
type.name.type2 = green
```

Problem: not only the text was translated, but the option keys, too!

So I tried to add a `optionKey='id'`:

```
<g:select name="type.id" from="${Type.list()}" 
         valueMessagePrefix="type.name"  
             value="${domainInstance?.type?.id}"  
                optionKey='id' />
```

This switched the keys to the id - great, but the text switched to the id, too :-(

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanx to grails beeing open source, I just checked the code: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html#select

It seems that valueMessagePrefix is ignored as soon as you use optionKey or optionValue. But optionValue can take a closure:

```
<g:select name="type.id" from="${Type.list()}" 
         value="${domainInstance?.type?.id}"  
            optionKey="id" 
            optionValue="${ {name->g.message(code:'type.name'+name) } }"/>
```

at least, this works.

Comment: thank you, but this didn't work, "name" in your closure will receive the object in g:select's "from" so you have to do this : (at least that what worked for me)
optionValue="${ {typeAbc->g.message(code:'type.name'+typeAbc.name) } I hope this helps someone :)
i renamed type to typeAbc to distinct it from your i18n prefix

Comment: I guess my answer is only valid for an older version of grails... Which version do you use?

Comment: 3.1.7, oh maybe this is why

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add an optionValue?

```
<g:select name="type.id" from="${Type.list()}" 
         valueMessagePrefix="type.name"  
             value="${domainInstance?.type?.id}"  
                optionKey='id' 
                optionValue='name'/>
```

Sorry I haven't had a chance to test this exact code, but have done similar things like this with no problems.

Comment: That's what I did. The result was the untranslated name.