# grails g:select i18n

Tags: grails, select, internationalization

I just read a lot and googled but I'm frustrated right now.

I have a Country domain model

```
class Country{
   String countryCode //maybe EN, DE, CH...
}
```

Now I want a translation inside the . I read in the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Tags/select.html) (and with google) that it is possible with the "id" to select it from the translation message property files. Something like:

```
country.code.1=America
country.code.2=England
country.code.3=Germany
```

But this is not what I want. I want to have something like:

```
country.code.US=America
country.code.EN=England
country.code.DE=Germany
```

So, I found a possible solution from stackoverflow: [translate a HTML select element in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948644/translate-a-html-select-element-in-grails)
that would mean for me I have to put it like this:

```
<g:select name="country"
          from="${allCountries}"
          value="${country}"
          optionKey="id"
          optionValue="${ {countryCode->g.message(code:'country.code.'+countryCode)}  }"/>
```

But my result is inside the dropdown: "country.code.grails.Country : 1" (and so on for each country)

If I change the last line of the gsp-g:select implementation to:

```
[...]optionValue="${ {countryCode->g.message(code:'country.code.US')}
```

as you see hardcoded! And THIS works :-D

Hope you got me and can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. Instead of sending the id to the controller, use the `contryCode` instead of `id`:

   ```
   <g:select name="contryByCountryCode" 
       from="${countryCodes}" 
       valueMessagePrefix="com.yourcompany"/>
   ```

   Will produce:

   ```
   <select name="contryByCountryCode" id="contryByCountryCode" >
       <option value="US">United States<option>
       ...
   </select>
   ```

   If you have proper messages configured. In the backend you need to do something like:

   ```
   def country = Country.findByCountryCode(params.contryByCountryCode)
   ```
2. Do it manually:

   ```
   <select name="contryByCountryCode" id="contryByCountryCode" >
       <g:each in="${countryCodes}" var="country">
       <option value="${country.id}">
           ${message(code:"prefix" + country.countryCode)}
       <option>
       </g:each>
   </select>
   ```
3. Patch `g:select` to work in case `optionValue` and `messagePrefix` is defined ;-)

Comment: NO - doesn't work. my dropdown is filled with the database-values for countryCode like 'US', 'DE' and so on :-(

Comment: grails will resolve the labels by looking up the message for the key derived from `valueMessagePrefix + "." + value`